# What effect does karma have?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I'm wondering what effects your Karma has in Fallout New Vegas, since they introduced the reputation with different factions?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Karma is almost non existent in the game. The only use I can see at this point is affecting which companions will follow you. For example, you cannot have Cass as a follower while you remain evil (Technically, you can because of a quest you need her for, but if you talk to her while you have evil karma she will tell you three times to get your act together before she runs off forever).

So long answer short, its strictly for companions as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 10):

Karma also affects game endings.
http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout%3A_New_Vegas_endings

Comment: Can you, please, include more quotes from the link as an example? Probably under the spoiler. I understand, that this is a nice and detailed wiki, etc. etc. but content there may change and having short examples here may benefit the answer. (Still +1 from me).

Answer (score -3):

in freeside bad ralf and the other guy won't let you shop there and also if your good the king will send you presents a lot and also in bad the thugs in free side won't attack you they run from you

Comment: That's faction/location reputation, not karma